# How to check worker status in Asyncio?

Tags: python, return, python-asyncio, coroutine, worker

I am downloading data as author, title etc. I want to download *only two books at once* so I create one task for each one. When the download is finished I need to know.

If I use `queue.join()` I'll know when tasks are finished but I have to wait for both tasks, instead, I want to put the new item on queue as soon as a worker becomes 'free'.

How Do I know when a worker becomes available to get a new item?

Below, you find some code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
nTasks = 2
async def worker(name):
    while True:
        #Wait for new book item
        queue_item = await queue_.get()
    
        #Starts to download author, title etc...
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(download_books(queue_item, file))

    queue_.task_done()

async def main():
try:
                #We create 2 task at once
                count = 0
                while ( count < nTasks):
                        #Gets the book file name
                        mediaGet = ....
                        #Put on queue
                        await queue_.put(mediaGet)                    
                        #Next download
                        count = count + 1
                contaTask = 0        
                
                #Wait until tasks are finished
                await queue_.join()
```

Comment: @Jack Casey  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to put new item on queue as soon as a worker become 'free'

You shouldn't need to care when a worker becomes free - the whole point of having workers is that you have a fixed number of them (two in your case) and that they drain the queue as fast as they can. You shouldn't use `create_task()` inside the worker because then you spawn the task in the background and discard the worker limit.

The correct way to work with a queue can look like this:

```
async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        queue_item = await queue.get()
        await download_books(queue_item, file)
        queue.task_done()

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # create two workers
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker(queue)) for _ in 2]
    # populate the queue
    for media in ...:
        await queue.put(media)
    # wait for the workers to do their jobs
    await queue.join()
    # cancel the now-idle workers
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()
```

Comment: Hi , here :  `await queue_.put(mediaGet)`  you meant `await queue.put(mediaGet)` ? Without the underscore char

Comment: @Francesco Yes, the extra _ remained from your original naming.

Comment: another question; `queue.join()` wait until **both** tasks are finished.  but if, for instance, the first task finishes before the second task, the script will put the third item available on queue ( in place of the first one) or it will wait for the first and the second task? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Francesco I am confused by your question. When `queue.join()` is awaited, the queue contains _all_ tasks, so the script won't "put" the third item in the queue, it will be there from the beginning. The two workers will dequeue items off the queue as fast as they can without waiting for anything other than the previous task to have finished. That will ensure that exactly two tasks are being processed at any point (except at the very end, when the last task is being processed, and will remain the only one).

Comment: Solved. Fantastic user4815162342 Thanks